# GWT Google Maps API V3 - Detect click on place

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, google-maps-api-3

How can I detect when a place is clicked on a map and how can i read all the details for that place ?

Answer (score 0):

here is a part of code:

what to do :

```
private MouseEventCallback onRightClick = new MouseEventCallback() {
    @Override
    public void callback(HasMouseEvent mouse) {
        Window.alert("here :" + mouse.getLatLng().toUrlValue() ) ;
    }
};
```

And the way you say it must be called

```
Event.addListener( mapWidget.getMap(), MapEvent.rightclick.name(), onRightClick ) ;
```

Comment: Ok, but is there a way to find some other information ,for example, if the click is on a hotel or a company or to display it's name, address, phone number etc ?

Comment: for this, you have to call geocoding stuff in the package : com.google.gwt.maps.client.geocoder;

Comment: I believe those classes can provide basic information on the type, approximate address, name. But not the information regarding phone, email, webpage and other details. Is there a way to find that information using the Google gmaps V3 api ? (maybe i'm missing something)

Comment: on this subject, I'll not help you, I didn't use.

Comment: the fact is that I searched/browsed for some examples using the javascript api (not just the GWT library) and I could find any example. Still... I have a feeling that I missed something...